# Search result template and readability

Tags: website-design, html, css, search-results

This is my current layout:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/qVDL5.png]
[image]
The sentence on top means "Results in the WHOLE SITE for: abc"

"Whole site" becomes the name of the section if you're searching in a single section.

Then you see each result's title in blue and its section in green. The navbar split up the results based on the item type. In this case you have discussion and scenarios which belong to different section types (discussion tool and brainstorming tool) or, for example, if you're searching a single section, you could have item types like "discussion" and "comments", in the case of the discussion tool.

I can say this layout is decent considering I'm not a graphic designer and I have absolutely no background in UI design, web graphic, or anything else related.

Right now I'm looking for general (and maybe some obvious to experts) advice on readability, on the layout of the results page, and anything you can think of.

Comment: Your dummy results are very bad because they aren't close to representing real content.

Comment: good point, i'm posting a new screenshot soon.

Comment: 1) What kind of content is on the site? Why are users searching? 2) Where did search result snippets disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fonts to a size of 12-16 to get better readability. Your design typos look tiny. Now also the line spacing is important ie., the horizontal line spacing which should be 16 for a 14 point typo's, ie., one ahead of your font size.

Your perfect example for search page should be "Google". Try to follow the way they have laid out.

Try using Accessibility rules such as to increase font from the optimal size on your page. So that the typo's will stand tall for people who have to squint their eyes.

These are basic things you can address to start with.